# What is the generator of the fraction field of $K(y)[T]/(T^2-1-y^2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field, and let $y,T$ be transcendentals, then
$$K(y)[T]/(T^2-1-y^2) = K(f)$$
for some $f$. What is $f$?

Comment: Note that $T^2-y^2=1$ gives upon setting $x=T+y$, $y=T-y$ the equation $xy=1$, and both $x,y$ are trascendental. Does this help?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Aha, so $T-y$ or $T+y$ both generate. Great!

Comment: You have to assume $\operatorname{char}K\ne 2$.